# Position of the SpaceX barge for the January 10th launch

Tags: spacex

What was the on station position (lat, long) of the barge for the January 10th launch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ASDS forum](http://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=36326.750) over at NasaSpaceflight.com were lamenting the lack of satellite data for a precise fix, but they followed the GoQuest escort boat until it went out of range on vesselfinder.com:
[image]
Closer to launch time someone on the forum reported wave height at this closest buoy:
http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=41010&unit=M&tz=STN

The ships appear to be headed back in now:
http://www.vesselfinder.com/?mmsi=367017460

---

[Spaceflight 101](http://www.spaceflight101.com/dragon-spx-5-mission-updates.html) placed the ASDS here:

[image]